# "CountIF" formula not counting some cells

Tags: excel

I have an excel document with learners marks in one column and levels in the other. The levels are from 1 to 7 and have been inserted using the "Lookup" function. When I use  "countif" to find the number of learners in each level some cells are not counted. Retyping the levels manually solves the problem but its hectic for large lists.

Comment: Can you give the exact formula (the COUNTIF)? Are you sure there aren't other characters like spaces in the cells - that could make the count "incorrect"

Comment: An example of the formula that I'm using is =COUNTIFS(C5:C141,"F",I5:I141,"2"). Column C has gender "M" or "F". The leves are in column "I". There might be spaces as some numbers seem not to be aligned properly vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using wildcards like this

`=COUNTIFS(C5:C141,"F",I5:I141,"*2*")`

......or possibly wrap your LOOKUP formula in a TRIM function to get rid of any unwanted spaces

Comment: The wild cards have fixed the problem.I will also experiment with the TRIM function.